# Kairosdb not running

Tags: cassandra, kairosdb

i am trying to run kairosdb and cassandra, but kairosdb shutsdown after i get the following error, i believe it is because kairosdb is not able to establish connection with cassandra. Cassandra seems to be running fine and i cannot understand why this error is popping:

> 18:33:08.463 [main] ERROR [HConnectionManager.java:71] - Could not start connection pool for host localhost(127.0.0.1):9160
>
> Error injecting constructor, org.kairosdb.core.exception.DatastoreException: me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorException: All host pools marked down. Retry burden pushed out to client. ...

Also, i noticed that kairos_cache ix not created which is mentioned in this [link.](https://github.com/kairosdb/kairosdb/issues/152) I changed the permissions of the /tmp/ folder to user from root, still it is not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open your `cassandra.yaml` file and do the following:

- Check if you have the apache thrift rpc server enabled and if it is listening on the port Kairos is listening.

`start_rpc: true
rpc_address: localhost
rpc_port: 9160`

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Kairosdb and was facing the same issue. This helps

Answer (score 2):

The message is because KairosDB cannot reach Cassandra.

Probably your cassandra DB is not listening on 127.0.0.1 (loopback).

Check your cassandra.yaml file, probably it is using the IP Adress of your network interface as listen_adress and not 127.0.0.1.

Cassandra only listens on one address, by default it is the local host name of IP.

Otrherwise you may check your port just in case, but the ListenAddress is often the source of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a docker deployment of cassandra with KairosDB.

As @JVasques said in his answer, the parameter **"start_rpc"** is disabled (set to false) in the newest `cassandra.yaml` file as default.

If anyone needs a default/standard YAML configuration file, it is recommended to download the latest release or the version you are using. You can download it from the official cassandra package on the Apache Website: http://cassandra.apache.org/download/
It is located under `conf/cassandra.yaml`

Beware: Configuration files of older cassandra versions might not be compatible!

It worked with the following settings in Docker for me:

```
start_rpc: true
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
rpc_port: 9160
```